# Nixos default audio device

Tags: audio, alsa, nix, nixos, pulse

I'm trying to configure the default audio device on a NixOS host.

My alsa devices are thus:

```
$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: ALC1220 Analog [ALC1220 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 1: ALC1220 Digital [ALC1220 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I don't have HDMI or digitaul audio devices; I just want to use the regular ALC1220 Analog device.

I currently have `AUDIODEV=hw:1,0` set in my environment (for sox), and `alsa-audio-device=sysdefault:CARD=Generic` in my vlcrc.  That works, but it is obviously user- and app- specific, and is a pain for declaritiveness (declarity?).

It seems that it should be something I can set at the host level, e.g., by setting

```
sound.extraConfig =
  ''
    pcm.!default {
      type hw
      card Generic
    }
  '';
```

in my configuration.nix, or possibly configuring pulseaudio.

I have sought help in the NixOS Wiki ([ALSA](https://nixos.wiki/wiki/ALSA), [Pulse](https://nixos.wiki/wiki/PulseAudio)), on other sites such as [ArchLinux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Examples#Set_the_default_output_source), [Pulse documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/DefaultDevice/), and other sites like StackOverflow (e.g., [stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93128/alsa-how-can-i-tell-my-default-audio-output-is-card-2-and-device-0-not-hdmi)), but I can find nothing that actually works.

I have tried the above, and variants thereof; and also tried with & without Pulse; but I have found nothing that works.

Simply being able to sound audio to all the devices on that card would be jolly good, too.

As always, any pointers gratefully recieved.

**Update**: here is my /etc/asound.conf

```
pcm_type.pulse {
  libs.native = /nix/store/a3v4gh5lbb2g8fizq9xh8nbdp8qrvs6r-alsa-plugins-1.1.6/lib/alsa-lib/libasound_module_pcm_pulse.so ;

}
pcm.!default {
  type pulse
  hint.description "Default Audio Device (via PulseAudio)"
}
ctl_type.pulse {
  libs.native = /nix/store/a3v4gh5lbb2g8fizq9xh8nbdp8qrvs6r-alsa-plugins-1.1.6/lib/alsa-lib/libasound_module_ctl_pulse.so ;

}
ctl.!default {
  type pulse
}
```

(and that module is real):

```
$ ls -l /nix/store/a3v4gh5lbb2g8fizq9xh8nbdp8qrvs6r-alsa-plugins-1.1.6/lib/alsa-lib/libasound_module_ctl_pulse.so
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root root 33512 Jan  1  1970 /nix/store/a3v4gh5lbb2g8fizq9xh8nbdp8qrvs6r-alsa-plugins-1.1.6/lib/alsa-lib/libasound_module_ctl_pulse.so
```

Comment: Try the configuration `sound.enable = true;` and `hardware.pulseaudio.enable = true;`. Remove the `sound.extraConfig`. Then use `pavucontrol` to see which audio devices are detected.

Comment: Thanks for this.  So actually, I already have `sound.enable = true;` and `hardware.pulseaudio.enable = true;`; and removed the extraConfig.  Running pavucontrol shows me a single device - `Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) HD Audio Controller Analog Stereo` with ports line out (plugged in) and headphones (unplugged).  Still, running (say) `play` with AUDIODEV unset gives silence, where `AUDIODEV=hw:1,0` works (plays through the line out).

Comment: Hmm, maybe you're missing an PulseAudio ALSA plugin. Consider posting your `/etc/asound.conf`.

Comment: Sure, that's done.

Comment: Hmm... OK, try using `play` again without setting `AUDIODEV`, then run `pavucontrol` and go to the "playback" tab. Do you see "ALSA Plug-in" listed? Perhaps you also have "System Sounds". If you do see ALSA Plug-in, then perhaps it's muted. Note: The application needs to be producing audio (even if you can't hear it) for it to show up in the "playback" tab.

Comment: Annoyingly, now it's working - the `/etc/asound.conf` is as above, and I've unset `AUDIODEV`: it plays.  Fwiw, firing up `pavucontrol`, I see 'SoX: playback on' (I'm using `play`; and `System Sounds`.  Similar with vlc.  The one notable change... is that I updated my nixos from `19.03.f52505f` to `19.03.f29d398`, so maybe that was the issue. Either way, it ain't broke now.  Many thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is most likely due to pulseaudio comandeering the default device, despite listing it in ~/.asoundrc.

The best solution to override pulse's comandeering of the default device with an alsa hook. To do this, edit your ~/.asoundrc with the following contents at the top :

```
@hooks [
    {
        func load
        files [
            "~/.asoundrc"
        ]
        errors false
    }
]
```

You can then add you default device as required, probably something like the following in your case :

```
pcm.!default {
        type hw
        card "Generic"
}

ctl.!default {
  type hw
  card "Generic"
}
```